# Get User data in default.ctp

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, authorization, cakephp-2.3

I'm using Cake 2.3.5. I followed the Blog+Authentication tutorial on the main website. I want to alter it so that a welcome message displays in the header for all pages, so I need to get the username in default.ctp.

I have tried these methods:

```
//these don't work..

//in default.ctp
<div>Signed in as: <?php echo AuthComponent::user('username'); ?></div>

<?php $user = $this->Session->read('Auth.User');
echo $user['username']; ?>
```

Both always return null, and nothing gets printed, even on pages where I successfully get the username in a user view by setting a php variable in UsersController based on the id number that initiated the function:

```
//this works..

//in UsersController
$this->set('user', $this->User->read(null, $id));

//in users/view
<div>Signed in as: <?php echo $user['User']['username']; ?></div>
```

How can I get the logged in users data in default.ctp?

EDIT:

I'm having a problem with this:

```
    $user = $this->Session->read('Auth.User');
    $this->set('user', $user);
```

If I put this code in default:

```
echo $user['username'];
```

it works in home.ctp, but throws an 'index doesn't exist error' in any user views. If I change the code to:

```
echo $user['User']['username'];
```

I get the opposite problem (works on the user views, but throws an error on the homepage).

I tried putting this in AppController:

```
    $user = $this->Session->read('Auth.User');
    if (array_key_exists('User', $user))
        $user = $user['User'];
    $this->set('user', $user);
```

But nothing changed.

SOLUTION:

This is the easiest method:

```
//in default.ctp
$user = AuthComponent::user();
$username = $user['username'];
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simplest way is use `AuthComponent::user();`

Comment: how would you get the username after that?

Comment: AuthComponent::user('username');

Comment: Do You have field `username`? Do You use `echo` for it to display?

Comment: Yes. This displays nothing: <?php echo AuthComponent::user('username'); ?>

Answer (score 1):

In the beforefilter of the AppController use

```
function beforeFilter(){
    $user = $this->Session->read('Auth.User');
    $this->set('username', $user['username']);
}
```

Now, in default.ctp you can access $username;

Comment: this works, is it better practice than the other answer if I will be reading more data than just the username?

Comment: Using the beforeFilter in the AppController you can send any data you want to default.ctp. If you only want the user properties AuthComponent::user() is shorter. If you want other information (say, some kind of count or label), just throw it in the beforeFilter.

Comment: @Cbas To check the structure of the array simply use print_r($name_of_your_variable)